# to like something very much (of an animal)

Tags: clauses

Cows usually like to sit on the soil and they feel comfortable compared to a hard floor. And they feel anxiety if they are made to rest on a hard surface. But if there is soil, they feel it good. Which one describes it better:

*A. A cow is usually intimate to the soil.*

*B. The soil is an intimate thing for a cow.*

Comment: Intimacy isn't the same as comfort or preference. Why not say 'A cow feels more comfortable lying on the soil than on an artificial surface'? (BTW We say _intimate with_, not _to_.)

Comment: When I googled _cow sitting_, some pictures came up of a cow sitting up on her haunches with her front legs straight, as a dog does - but this is regarded as unusual. The cow in your photo would normally be described as _lying down_.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to remove your additional, direct question to me - that wasn't really appropriate to name me in your question, plus it removed the focus from your question and made it off-topic. In answer to the question though, cows and other large quadrupeds don't really "sit" - they rest either standing up or lying down. Although that isn't really a question about English.

Comment: @ Astralbee My apologies

Comment: BTW aren't sitting, lying, resting English words? and to learn the differences between these, IS English, I think.

Answer (score 2):

'Intimate' isn't the right word at all, nor have you used it correctly. Intimacy between two persons implies a deep, personal *relationship*, the kind characterised by reciprocated feelings that 'soil' cannot give. The word can also be used to refer to something personal and secret. Your second example sounds like the soil is something the cow keeps hidden away.

I don't think you need to say anything deeper than "cows like to lie on the soil". I'm not that sure you can really attribute any other kind of driving force behind that preference other than their instinct. As you said, they'd lie somewhere else if they had to, but they *prefer* to lie on the soil. I don't believe that anyone but a cow can say how lying on the soil makes them 'feel'.

[This article](https://www.heart.co.uk/news/quirky/real-reason-cows-lie-down-raining-truth/) says:

> The truth is nobody really knows for certain why these herbivores lie down from time to time.
> However, there are several theories!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Astralbee and others, "intimate" is not the right word here. ([See this entry from Oxford Dictionary.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/intimate_1))

I also think it is more common to talk about a cow "lying on" or "lying down on" rather than "sitting on" a surface. (Not that sitting is wrong.)

You can take your pick from the following:

1. (If/When) given the choice, cows prefer to lie on the soil rather than...
2. (If/When) given the choice, cows would opt for the soil rather than...
3. Cows tend to lie on the soil rather than...
4. Cows are more comfortable lying on the soil than... (Thanks to @KateBunting)
5. Cows are more at home on the soil than...
6. Cows are more at home lying on the soil than...
7. Cows have a net preference for the soil over hard surfaces.

---

Here is an ngram:

[image]

And here is another one:

[image]

Comment: I think the only reason to talk about cows sitting is if you want to differentiate a cow lying down with its legs underneath it (which you might call "sitting") from a cow sprawling on its side or lying in another posture, which is definitely "lying". [Sitting](https://www.shutterstock.com/search/cat+sitting+on+floor) for animals often means resting on haunches with upper body supported by extended forelegs, as with a cat or dog. A cow doesn't do this: [even when standing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htc-o5HXer8) it rises to its hindlegs before straightening its forelegs.